# sending multiple files as attachment in e-mail using mailx

Tags: bash, shell, unix, mailx

I have a requiremnet to send multiple files as e-mail attachmnet in shell script. I have used below command.

```
(printf "%s\n" "BODY"; uuencode out.txt out.txt ; uuencode asgda.txt asgda.txt ) | mailx -m -s "TEST" emailid@domain.com
```

However the number of files i want to send as an attachmnet are dynamic. So I want to assign the uuencode ... comand to a variable and then use it. I have tried below way,

```
$ ATTACH_CMD=$(echo `cat $OUTPUT_FILE`)
$ echo $ATTACH_CMD
uuencode out.txt out.txt ; uuencode asgda.txt asgda.txt

$ (printf "%s\n" "BODY"; $ATTACH_CMD ) | mailx -m -s "TEST" emailid@domain.com
```

And i am getting below error.

```
sh: uuencode out.txt out.txt ; uuencode asgda.txt asgda.txt:  not found.
```

Can any one please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried below today  -     $ echo $(echo $ATTACH_CMD )
    uuencode out.txt out.txt; uuencode out.txt out.txt     (printf "%s\n" "BODY"; $(echo $ATTACH_CMD ) ) | mailx -m -s "TEST" mail@domain.com I have received e-mail but attachmnet is not received. Instead bosy has tect "Usage: uuencode [ source ] remotedest" Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way. eval makes the trick

```
eval $STR 

$ ATTACH_CMD=$(echo `cat $OUTPUT_FILE`)
$ echo $ATTACH_CMD
uuencode out.txt out.txt ; uuencode asgda.txt asgda.txt

$ (printf "%s\n" "BODY"; eval $ATTACH_CMD ) | mailx -m -s "TEST" emailid@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the below code? Not sure why it works, but maybe the below code could be used as a workaround

```
(printf "%s\n" "BODY"; `echo $ATTACH_CMD` ) | mailx -m -s "TEST" emailid@domain.com`?
```

For `$ATTACH_CMD` I have used `echo` command.